# How can I comment on apps shown in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-installation

How does one add comments regarding the programs installed from the GUI software installer?

I just tried a program that turned out to be a pay-for version, and don't know how to add a comment for others to read prior to downloading.

Comment: Which GUI software installer are you asking about? There are several supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign up for a (free, spamfree) [Launchpad.net](https://login.launchpad.net/+login) account. Once you are registered, go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center and post a bug message about the product in question.

Comment: Much better, I appreciate that hugely.